# Unable to hide or show div based on radio button selection in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a requirement, where in I display the fields based on radio button selection.
Below is the code -

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#selection_0').select(function () {
            $('#text_to_speech').show();
            $('#recorded_messages').hide();
            $('#recorded_messages').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true)});
            $('#text_to_speech').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('disabled', false)});


        });

        $('#selection_1').select(function () {
            $('#recorded_messages').show();
            $('#text_to_speech').hide();
            $('#recorded_messages').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('disabled', false)});
            $('#text_to_speech').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true)});

        });
    });
```

I'm unable to make this code work. There is no error in console as well.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/msn4an49/)

Comment: [`.select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/) is not for radio buttons i guess! and fiddle isn't having jQuery library included!

Comment: You can use on click like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/msn4an49/5/

Comment: and your fiddle has no jquery added@user3004356

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[name=someRadioGroup]:radio").change(function () {
//Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#selection_0').click(function () {
                alert(4)
                $('#text_to_speech').show();
                $('#recorded_messages').hide();
                $('#recorded_messages').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('disabled', true)});
                $('#text_to_speech').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('disabled', false)});


            });

            $('#selection_1').click(function () {
                alert(7)
                $('#recorded_messages').show();
                $('#text_to_speech').hide();
                $('#recorded_messages').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('disabled', false)});
                $('#text_to_speech').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('disabled', true)});

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.change` event instead of `.select`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/rf0kmqpo/)

Answer (score 0):

See the demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rf0kmqpo/1/).

This should work for you..

```
$("#selection :input[name=selection]").change(function () {
    var radioId = $(this).attr("id");
    if(radioId=='selection_0'){
    }
    else{
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

select will not work here. Use change or click events.

```
              $( document ).ready(function() {
                    $('#selection_0').click(function () {
                        if ($('#selection_0').is(':checked')) {
                            $('#text_to_speech').show();
                            $('#recorded_messages').hide();
                            $('#recorded_messages').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                                $(this).prop('disabled', true)});
                            $('#text_to_speech').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                                $(this).prop('disabled', false)});
                        }

                });

                    $('#selection_1').click(function () {
                        if ($('#selection_1').is(':checked')) {
                            $('#recorded_messages').show();
                            $('#text_to_speech').hide();
                            $('#recorded_messages').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                                $(this).prop('disabled', false)
                            });
                            $('#text_to_speech').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
                                $(this).prop('disabled', true)
                            });
                        }
                });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following JQuery code

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("input[name='selection']").on('change', function () {

    if ($("input[name='selection']:checked").val() == 0) {           
        $('#text_to_speech').show();
        $('#recorded_messages').hide();
        $('#recorded_messages').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true)});
        $('#text_to_speech').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false)});
     }else{
        $('#recorded_messages').show();
        $('#text_to_speech').hide();
        $('#recorded_messages').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false)});
        $('#text_to_speech').find('input, textarea, button, select').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true)});

    }});
});
```

please note that the div's  **recorded_messages** and **text_to_speech** have same html so it may appear as if there is no change happening